# Pybrain - SequentialDataSet using Backprop trainer give a slice indices error

Tags: python, neural-network, lstm, pybrain

I searched throughout the inter-webs for this one, didnt find anything, except for a 'deleted' post on stack overflow.

The problem is the following :
Every examples, tutorials on PyBrain **LSTM** + **SequencialDataSet**  givwa me the following error :

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

From my previous searches, it seems to be a problem where, after a certain version of python, integer operations returns *float* instead of *integers*

However, it seems to work with everyone else using python 2.x like me.
Any idea ?

Code (Which is not mine, took from another stackoverflow post) :

```
from pybrain.tools.shortcuts import buildNetwork
from pybrain.supervised.trainers import BackpropTrainer
from pybrain.datasets import SequentialDataSet
from pybrain.structure import SigmoidLayer, LinearLayer
from pybrain.structure import LSTMLayer

import itertools
import numpy as np

INPUTS = 5
OUTPUTS = 1
HIDDEN = 40

net = buildNetwork(INPUTS, HIDDEN, OUTPUTS, hiddenclass=LSTMLayer,     outclass=LinearLayer, recurrent=True, bias=True)

ds = SequentialDataSet(INPUTS, OUTPUTS)
ds.addSample([0,1,2,3,4],[5])
ds.addSample([5,6,7,8,9],[10])
ds.addSample([10,11,12,13,14],[15])
ds.addSample([16,17,18,19,20],[21])

net.randomize()

trainer = BackpropTrainer(net, ds)

for _ in range(1000):
    print trainer.train()

x=net.activate([0,1,2,3,4])
print x
```

Which gives me this error :

```
File "try3.py", line 27, in <module>
print trainer.train()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/supervised/trainers/backprop.py", line 57, in train
for seq in self.ds._provideSequences():
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py", line 173, in _provideSequences
return iter(map(list, iter(self)))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py", line 169, in __iter__
yield self.getSequenceIterator(i)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py", line 63, in getSequenceIterator
return zip(*self.getSequence(index))
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py", line 56, in getSequence
return [self._getSequenceField(index, l) for l in self.link]
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PyBrain-0.3.3-py2.7.egg/pybrain/datasets/sequential.py", line 45, in _getSequenceField
return self.getField(field)[seq[index]:]
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Using :

```
Python 2.7.6 (default, Oct 26 2016, 20:30:19)
[GCC 4.8.4] on linux2
```

Comment: It works on Python 2.7.9 for me, no problems.  My crucial modules are: Python 2.7.9, scipy 0.14.0 and pybrain 0.3.  Have a look what versions you have

Comment: Sure thing : Python 2.7.6, scipy 0.18.1, PyBrain-0.3.3

Comment: Ok, I have just had a go with your versions in a virtualenv and the error appeared.  Something has changed in the versions you have and what I have.  One answer would be to use a virtualenv with a later python and modules or upgrade yours.  I haven't dug into what exactly is causing this and where the difference is yet. Hope this helps,

Comment: Perfect mate, thanks for you answer !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it, the difference is in pybrain, this fixed it in my setup:

```
pip uninstall pybrain
pip install pybrain
```

Try that,

Comment: MMM same error on my side...doesnt matter, i'll setup my python so it has the same version as yours, i'll let you know if it works !